# Snake Game Object Oriented Approach

Tags: c++, object-oriented, design-patterns, snake-game

I just completed a snake game using object-oriented programming. The focus is on the class implementation.

## OVERVIEW

Snake game works by moving the snake in order to eat fruits whilst escaping obstacles such as walls and itself.

## Aim

1. To conform to SOLID design pattern.

## food.h

```
#ifndef SNAKEXENXIA_FOOD_H_
#define SNAKEXENXIA_FOOD_H_

class Food
{
    public:
        Food()
            : food_char( 'O' ), x_location( 0 ), y_location( 0 ), food_size( 3 ) {}
        Food( const char food_chr )
            : food_char( food_chr ), x_location( 0 ), y_location( 0 ), food_size( 3 ) {}
        Food( const char food_chr, const unsigned x_loc, const unsigned y_loc, const unsigned sz )
            : food_char( food_chr ), x_location( x_loc ), y_location( y_loc ), food_size( sz ) {}

        char get_food_char() const { return food_char; }
        Food& set_food_char( const char val )
        {
            food_char = val;
            return *this;
        }

        unsigned get_x_location() const { return x_location; }
        Food& set_x_location( const unsigned val )
        {
            x_location = val;
            return *this;
        }

        unsigned get_y_location() const { return y_location; }
        Food& set_y_location( const unsigned val )
        {
            y_location = val;
            return *this;
        }

        unsigned get_food_size() const { return food_size; }
        Food& set_food_size( const unsigned val )
        {
            food_size = val;
            return *this;
        }
    private:
        char food_char;
        unsigned x_location;
        unsigned y_location;
        unsigned food_size;
};

#endif // SNAKEXENXIA_FOOD_H_
```

## snakebody.h

```
#ifndef SNAKEXENXIA_SNAKEBODY_H
#define SNAKEXENXIA_SNAKEBODY_H

#include <iostream>

enum class COORD {
    /* This specifies where the snake individual body is
        relative to North, South, East, West */
    N = 1,
    S = 2,
    E = 3,
    W = 4,
};

class SnakeBody
{
    public:
        SnakeBody() = default;
        SnakeBody( const char body_chr, const COORD &coord, unsigned number )
            : snake_co_ordinate( coord ),
            x_location( 0 ), y_location( 0 ), snake_body_char( body_chr ), body_number( number ){}
        SnakeBody( const unsigned x_loc, const unsigned y_loc, const char body_chr, const COORD &coord,\
                    const unsigned number )
                    : snake_co_ordinate( coord ),
            x_location( x_loc ), y_location( y_loc ), snake_body_char( body_chr ), body_number( number ){}

        unsigned get_x_location() const { return x_location; }
        SnakeBody& set_x_location( const unsigned val )
        {   x_location = val;
            return *this;
        }

        unsigned get_y_location() const { return y_location; }
        SnakeBody& set_y_location( const unsigned val )
        {   y_location = val;
            return *this;
        }

        char get_snake_body_char() const { return snake_body_char; }
        SnakeBody& set_snake_body_char( const char val )
        {   snake_body_char = val;
            return *this;
        }

        unsigned get_number() const { return body_number; }
        bool operator==( const SnakeBody &sb ) const;

        COORD snake_co_ordinate;
    private:
        unsigned x_location;
        unsigned y_location;
        char snake_body_char;
        unsigned body_number; // unique number to diffrentiate each snakebody
};

#endif // SNAKEXENXIA_SNAKEBODY_H
```

## snakebody.cpp

```
#include "snakebody.h"

bool SnakeBody::operator==( const SnakeBody &sb ) const
{
    if( x_location != sb.x_location ) return false;
    if( y_location != sb.y_location ) return false;
    if( snake_body_char != sb.snake_body_char ) return false;
    if( snake_co_ordinate != sb.snake_co_ordinate ) return false;
    if( body_number != sb.body_number ) return false;

    return true;
}
```

## snake.h

```
#ifndef SNAKEXENXIA_SNAKE_H
#define SNAKEXENXIA_SNAKE_H

#include "snake.h"
#include <vector>
#include "snakebody.h"

class Snake
{
    public:
        Snake( const char body_chr )
            : snake_char( body_chr ), can_move_north( true ), can_move_south( true ),
                can_move_west( true ), can_move_east( false ) {
                body.push_back( SnakeBody( 20, 20, 'H', COORD::W, 1 ) );
                body.push_back( SnakeBody( 20, 21, snake_char, COORD::W, 2 ) );
            }

        char get_snake_char() const { return snake_char; }
        Snake& set_snake_char( const char val )
        {   snake_char = val;
            return *this;
        }
        void eat() { grow(); }
        void move_north();
        void move_south();
        void move_west();
        void move_east();
        const std::vector<SnakeBody>& get_snake() const { return body; }
        unsigned get_snake_head_x() const { return body.front().get_x_location(); }
        unsigned get_snake_head_y() const { return body.front().get_y_location(); }

    private:
        std::vector<SnakeBody> body;
        char snake_char;
        bool can_move_north;
        bool can_move_south;
        bool can_move_east;
        bool can_move_west;

         /* This holds the current location of the snake
            Before moving N, S, E, W */
        unsigned move_x;
        unsigned move_y;

        void grow();
        void move_snake( const COORD &coord );
        void set_snake_valid_moves( const COORD &coord );
};

#endif // SNAKEXENXIA_SNAKE_H
```

## snake.cpp

```
#include "snake.h"

void Snake::grow()
{
    unsigned tail_x = body.back().get_x_location();
    unsigned tail_y = body.back().get_y_location();
    unsigned number = body.back().get_number();

    if( body.back().snake_co_ordinate == COORD::N ) {
        SnakeBody sb( ++tail_x, tail_y, snake_char, COORD::N, ++number );
        body.push_back(sb);
    }
    else if( body.back().snake_co_ordinate == COORD::S ) {
        SnakeBody sb( --tail_x, tail_y, snake_char, COORD::S, ++number);
        body.push_back(sb);
    }
    else if( body.back().snake_co_ordinate == COORD::E ) {
        SnakeBody sb( tail_x, ++tail_y, snake_char, COORD::E, ++number );
        body.push_back(sb);
    }
    else if( body.back().snake_co_ordinate == COORD::W ) {
       SnakeBody sb( tail_x, --tail_y, snake_char, COORD::W, ++number );
       body.push_back(sb);
    }
    else
        return;
}

void Snake::move_north()
{
    if( can_move_north )
        move_snake( COORD::N );
    return;
}

void Snake::move_south()
{
    if( can_move_south )
        move_snake( COORD::S );
    return;
}

void Snake::move_east()
{
    if( can_move_east )
        move_snake( COORD::E );
    return;
}

void Snake::move_west()
{
    if( can_move_west )
        move_snake( COORD::W );
    return;
}

void Snake::move_snake( const COORD &coord )
{
    move_x = body.front().get_x_location();
    move_y = body.front().get_y_location();

    unsigned temp_x = 0;
    unsigned temp_y = 0;

    switch( coord )
    {
        case COORD::N:
            body.front().set_x_location( move_x - 1 );
            break;
         case COORD::S:
            body.front().set_x_location( move_x + 1 );
            break;
         case COORD::E:
            body.front().set_y_location( move_y + 1 );
            break;
         case COORD::W:
            body.front().set_y_location( move_y - 1 );
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    for( auto &item : body )
    {
        item.snake_co_ordinate = coord;
        if( item == body.front() )
            continue;

        /* get x and y location of snakebody before it moves */
        temp_x = item.get_x_location();
        temp_y = item.get_y_location();

        item.set_x_location( move_x );
        item.set_y_location( move_y );

        /* store the x and y for next snakebody move */
        move_x = temp_x;
        move_y = temp_y;

    }
    set_snake_valid_moves( coord );
}

void Snake::set_snake_valid_moves( const COORD &coord )
{
    switch( coord )
    {
        case COORD::N:
            can_move_east = true;
            can_move_south = false;
            can_move_west = true;
            can_move_north = true;
            break;
         case COORD::S:
            can_move_east = true;
            can_move_north = false;
            can_move_west = true;
            can_move_south = true;
            break;
         case COORD::E:
            can_move_west = false;
            can_move_north = true;
            can_move_south = true;
            can_move_east = true;
            break;
         case COORD::W:
            can_move_east = false;
            can_move_north = true;
            can_move_south = true;
            can_move_west = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I also included `main`. ncurses.h is required to run main

## main.cpp

````
#include "food.h"
#include "snake.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

#include <ncurses.h>

constexpr int HEIGHT = 30;
constexpr int WIDTH = 80;

std::default_random_engine engine ( static_cast<unsigned int> (time( nullptr )) );
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> random_WIDTH( 1, HEIGHT );
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> random_HEIGHT( 1, WIDTH );

void set_food( WINDOW *win, Food &food, unsigned HEIGHT, unsigned WIDTH );
void display_snake( WINDOW *win, const std::vector<SnakeBody>& snake );
void display_food( WINDOW *win, const Food &food );
bool game_over( unsigned HEIGHT, unsigned WIDTH,  const std::vector<SnakeBody>& snake );

int main()
{
    srand( static_cast<unsigned int> (time( nullptr )) );
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    curs_set( 0 );

    int start_y = ( LINES - HEIGHT ) / 2;
    int start_x = ( COLS - WIDTH ) / 2;
    refresh();

    WINDOW *win = newwin( HEIGHT, WIDTH, start_y, start_x );
    keypad( win, true );

    box( win, 0, 0 );
    wrefresh( win );

    /* Initialize the game */
    Food game_food('*', 4, 5, 4 );
    Snake game_snake( 'O' );
    std::vector<SnakeBody> snake_vector = game_snake.get_snake();
    set_food( win, game_food, HEIGHT, WIDTH );
    display_food( win, game_food );
    display_snake( win, snake_vector );
    unsigned head_x, head_y;
    bool game_is_over = false;

    while( !game_is_over )
    {
        int c = wgetch( win );
        switch( c )
        {
            case KEY_UP:
                game_snake.move_north();
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                game_snake.move_south();
                break;
            case KEY_LEFT:
                game_snake.move_west();
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                game_snake.move_east();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        snake_vector = game_snake.get_snake();
        game_is_over = game_over( HEIGHT, WIDTH, snake_vector );

        /* clear and reinitialize the screen */
        wclear( win );
        display_food( win, game_food );
        box( win, 0, 0 );
        display_snake( win, snake_vector );
        wrefresh( win );

        head_x = game_snake.get_snake_head_x();
        head_y = game_snake.get_snake_head_y();
        if( head_x == game_food.get_x_location() && head_y == game_food.get_y_location() ) {
            game_snake.eat();
            mvwaddch( win, game_food.get_y_location(), game_food.get_x_location(), ' ' );
            set_food( win, game_food, HEIGHT, WIDTH );
            wrefresh( win );
        }
    }
    endwin();
}

void set_food( WINDOW *win, Food &food, unsigned height, unsigned width ) {
    unsigned x = random_WIDTH( engine );
    unsigned y = random_HEIGHT( engine );

    while( x > height - 2 || y > width - 2 ) {
        x = random_WIDTH( engine );
        y = random_HEIGHT( engine );
    }
    food.set_x_location( x ).set_y_location( y );
}

void display_snake( WINDOW *win, const std::vector<SnakeBody>& snake )
{
    for( const auto &item : snake )
    {
        mvwaddch( win, item.get_x_location(), item.get_y_location(), item.get_snake_body_char() );
    }
}

void display_food( WINDOW *win, const Food &food )
{
    mvwaddch( win, food.get_x_location(), food.get_y_location(), food.get_food_char() );
}

bool game_over( unsigned height, unsigned width,  const std::vector<SnakeBody>& snake )
{
    unsigned snake_head_x = snake.front().get_x_location();
    unsigned snake_head_y = snake.front().get_y_location();

    if( snake_head_x > height - 2 || snake_head_x <= 0 )
        return true;
     if( snake_head_y > width - 2 || snake_head_y <= 0 )
        return true;

    for( const auto &item : snake ) {
        if( item == snake.front() )
            continue;
        if( item.get_x_location() == snake_head_x && item.get_y_location() == snake_head_y )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Avoid setters and getters

```cpp
        unsigned get_x_location() const { return x_location; }
        Food& set_x_location( const unsigned val );
        unsigned get_y_location() const { return y_location; }
        Food& set_y_location( const unsigned val );
```

For such a simple variable like `x_location`, having a setter/getter pair just means writing more lines for no good reason, why not make `x_location` public in the first place? 
Now there is no point in the variable being `private`. If you keep following this pattern, you'll be forced to create a new getter/setter pair for every new variable that should be `public`

Your new `Food` class would be

```cpp
struct Food
{
    char food_char;
    unsigned x_location;
    unsigned y_location;

    // ctors..
};
```

This applies to all of your other classes

---

## Representing a position

You have a lot of these pairs

```cpp
unsigned x_location;
unsigned y_location;
```

I highly recommend you use [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) for this and just keep `position`. Even something like

```cpp
struct Position
{
    int x, y;

    Position(const int x, const int y)
        : x(x), y(y)
    {}
};
```

will be much better.

```cpp
Position position;
```

---

## Unnecessary `return;`

```cpp
void Snake::move_north()
{
    if( can_move_north )
        move_snake( COORD::N );
    return;
}

void Snake::move_south()
{
    if( can_move_south )
        move_snake( COORD::S );
    return;
}

void Snake::move_east()
{
    if( can_move_east )
        move_snake( COORD::E );
    return;
}

void Snake::move_west()
{
    if( can_move_west )
        move_snake( COORD::W );
    return;
}
```

What purpose do these `return;` statements serve here? **Nothing**, they are quite unnecessary here.

---

## `set_snake_valid_moves()`

Let's have a look at this function

```cpp
void Snake::set_snake_valid_moves( const COORD &coord )
{
    switch( coord )
    {
        case COORD::N:
            can_move_east = true;
            can_move_south = false;
            can_move_west = true;
            can_move_north = true;
            break;
         case COORD::S:
            can_move_east = true;
            can_move_north = false;
            can_move_west = true;
            can_move_south = true;
            break;
         case COORD::E:
            can_move_west = false;
            can_move_north = true;
            can_move_south = true;
            can_move_east = true;
            break;
         case COORD::W:
            can_move_east = false;
            can_move_north = true;
            can_move_south = true;
            can_move_west = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I have a problem here. Out of the 4 directions, there will always be only one direction that the snake cannot move to. So instead of having 4 directions = `can_move_west, can_move_east`..., why not just have **one** `cannot_move` direction?

```cpp
void Snake::set_snake_valid_moves( const COORD &coord )
{
    switch( coord )
    {
        case COORD::N:
            cannot_move == COORD::S;
            break;
         case COORD::S:
            cannot_move = COORD::N;
            break;
         case COORD::E:
            cannot_move = COORD::W;
            break;
         case COORD::W:
            cannot_move = COORD::E;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Or,

```cpp
if      (coord == COORD::S) cannot_move = COORD::N;
else if (coord == COORD::E) cannot_move = COORD::W;
else if (coord == COORD::W) cannot_move = COORD::E;
else if (coord == COORD::N) cannot_move = COORD::S;
```

That way, when you have to check if a certain `direction` is valid i.e doesn't break this rule, you can simply do

```cpp
if ( direction != cannot_move) //...
```

as simple as that

---

## When should you pass by `&`

I see a lot of

```cpp
const COORD &coord
```

When you pass by reference, you are implicitly passing a pointer to the object. In this case, `COORD` has an underlying type of `int`.

The size of `int` differs a lot, mostly it is 4-bytes. You can check for yourself by doing
`std::cout << sizeof(int);`. For me, it's 4.

As I said, passing by reference implicitly passes a pointer. The size of a pointer is **8 bytes**. which is double the size of `int`.
It's doing you no good. As a rule of thumb, you don't need to pas the primitive types i.e `int, char, float` as a reference. However, if you have something bigger like a `std::vector`, passing by value will be much more expensive.

---

## Moving the snake

After I read your method, I understand that you are updating the whole body of the snake by assigning the position of `snake[n]` to `snake[n+1`. While this is okay, I propose another method. 
What you can do here is pop back the last part of the snake, or its `tail` and add that to the front.

[image]

Procedure

- Pop the last element
- Create a new body part
- Set its new position to be `positon_of_head + offset` where offset is the change ( the distance to be moved ). Basically, the future position of the head
- Repeat

For this, you need to just a container like [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) which allowest fast insertion/deletion at both ends

 `std::vector` doesn't work here since it has a very slow insertion at front

---

## Smaller suggestions

- `void eat() { grow; }`?? Why create this bridge, just make `grow()` public
- Keep your `main()` clean, create another file / class to handle the GUI

## final thoughts

I like the design of your program, here are some things that I **don't like**

- Overcomplication of many classes. Keep it simple, there only a few attributes `Food` can have, but at first glance, it looks huge
- Noise in `main.cpp`. I don't like the GUI handling in main, I highly suggest that you create a class of its own, which would handle all of that
- 

Comment: Great. Thanks for the really optimized snake movement algorithm. smashed an O(n) operation to O(1).

Comment: I had a thought about the grow(). I came to this conclusion, the user should not have a say about whether the snake grows or not, all the user can do is simply make the snake eat. Though the snakes grows whenever it eats :)

Comment: If I may ask, calling snakebody constructor every single time a movement is made, won't that be quite expensive.

Comment: @theProgrammer You've actually over complicated the snake body class a lot, it should just be containing a position and it's character. With that, no.

Comment: If you have more than one value to return from a function then passing basic variables by reference does make sense. If speed is a concern then passing basic variables by reference may also make sense so that the copy doesn't happen.

Comment: @pacmanibw Yes that's true, but in this case that wasn't the intent

Comment: @Aryan Parekh. Great review, but I was hoping to get a review on the class design, if it follows SOLID design pattern, that's my major concern.

Comment: @theProgrammer I have edited my answer and put in my thoughts